# How to setup a specific tomact version to spring boot application in IntelliJ IDEA 2023

Tags: intellij-idea

I have 2 Tomcat versions, 9 and 10, in IntelliJ 2023. And I would like that one of my Springboot app 2.7.3 runs with Tomcat version 10 but it always runs with version 9

I'm trying to figure out how to do it but I can't find it.

Thank you so much for your help.